# Can't type in input field?

Tags: reactjs

I am not to sure why I can't seem to write in the input text field, I can log the event target value into the console but when I type into the text field the value is blank. I am not quite sure why. Yes I do understand there is a typo in the variable name initialStat.

Here is the code:

```js
export default function Form() {

    const initialStat = {
        techniqueName: "",
        Instructor: "",
        date: "",
        summary: "",
        mainPoints: "",
        rollSummary: "",
    }

    const [ourState, ourSetState] = useState(initialStat);

    function handleEventChange(event) {
        ourSetState({ ...ourState, [event.target.name]: event.target.value });
        console.log(event.target.value);
      }

      const {techniqueName, Instrtuctor, date, summary, mainPoints, rollSummary} = ourState;

    return (
            <div>
            Name: <input type="text" name="TechniqueName" value={techniqueName} onChange={handleEventChange} /> 
            </div>
       
    )
}
```

Comment: Is there a typo in `name="TechniqueName"` ? (lowercase the T)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `name` attribute is `TechniqueName` but your variable is `techniqueName`.

So `[event.target.name]: event.target.value` is like setting `{ TechniqueName:value }`

change the name attribute to match the case of your variable.

```
<input type="text" name="techniqueName" value={techniqueName} onChange={handleEventChange} />
```